# ¿Por qué no imprime en la misma línea las dos funciones y además también devuelve none?

Tags: python, spyder

> Estas son las funciones:

```
def names():
    print("sarah")
    print("megan")

def points():
    print("2")
    print("5")

def total():
    print(names(),points())
```

Sin embargo cuando pongo en la consola: total() la consola me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
sarah
megan
2
5
none 
none
```

Hay alguna manera de que me pueda devolver?:

```
sarah 2
megan 5
```

Answer (score 2):

bienvenido a StackOverflow en español.

Tu problema es tus funciones names() y point(), imprimen en consola el texto que les das con "print" y al ejecutar esas funciones dentro del print(names(), points()) lo que haces realmeten es no imprimir nada y ejecutar las acciones de los metodos que son print("st") y muestra en la consola. Lo que debes hacer es que esas funciones te retornen una lista de los elementos y luego recorrerlas en orden. tu código quedaría así:

```
def names():
    return ["sarah","megan"]

def points():
    return [2,5]

def total():

    list_names = names()
    list_points = points()

    for i in range(len(list_names)):
        print(list_names[i],list_points[i])

total()
```

Espero te sea util.

Comment: Muchas gracias me has ayudado un monton!

Comment: Existe alguna manera que en vez de print se pueda hacer con return?

Comment: Hola, no entiendo tu pregunta, un return donde?

Comment: En la funcion total en vez de un print al acabar un bucle un return.

Comment: Te refieres a poder hacer un print(total())?

Comment: Es el return para que cuando en la consola ponga total() me lo devuelva como out: como lo he pedido. Si cambio ese print por return me devuelve unicamente una linea, es para saber como si quisiera cambiar ese print por un return darme el mismo resultado.

Comment: Entiendo, si es posible, puedes crear una variable y llenarla dentro el for para retornarla al terminar el for y funciona..

Comment: Asi que igualo el bucle de abajo a una variable x y luego pongo return x?

Comment: Declara la variable antes de iniciar el for a un string vacío `x=""`, luego dentro del for cambia el print por `x=x+list_names[i]+" "+list_points[i]+"\n"` y finalmente haces el `return x` al salir del for

Comment: me devuelve este error: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: Es porque la lista de points es numérica usa str(list_points[i])

Comment: Me devuelve en solo una linea esto: 'sarah 2\nmegan 5\n'

Comment: Sí haces un print(total()), vas a obtener el resultado deseado. en este caso la shell no interpreta los saltos de linea y por eso ves los \n y no los saltos de linea.